# Posting data to another Site with Django

Tags: python, django, post

I would appreciate some help here.
Google checkout has many ways to send it checkout data. I am using the XML server-to-server.
I have everything ready and now I want to throw some xml at google. **I have been doing some reading** and I know of a couple of ways to do this, one with urllib, another with pyCurl, but I am using django over here and **I searched** the Django api for some way to POST data to another site and I havent fallen upon anything. I really would like to use the django way, if there is one because I feel it would be more fluid and right, but if you all don't know of any way I will probably use urllib.

Comment: I would suggest the wonderful [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/index.html) library

Comment: Requests is fabulous. If you're looking for a different provider entirely, I might recommend https://stripe.com/, which comes with official Python bindings.

Comment: I would love to use this stripe deal, but this site can't have ssl, its sort of a site where we want to spend 0 money to start with. Bu thatnk you so much my friend Jesus loves you man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urllib2 is the appropriate way to post data if you're looking for python standard library.  Django doesn't provide a specific method to do this (as well as it shouldn't).  Django goes out of it's way to not simply reinvent tools that already exist in the the standard library (except email...), so you should never really fear using something out of the python standard library.

requests is also great, but not standard library.  Nothing wrong with that though.

Comment: I think the simplicity of requests makes it a defacto replacement for all but the most complex tasks in the "send something to a webpage/fetch something from a webpage" domain. +1